# Adding events to all p tags

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to add an event for all elements with "p" tag,
but instead of adding an event script colors all links in red:

```
<script>
//create links
var code = ""
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
code += "<p><a href='#'>Link " + i + "</a></p>"
}
document.getElementById('links').innerHTML = code;
//add Events
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;i++){
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].onmouseover = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].childNodes[0].style.color="green"
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].onmouseout = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].childNodes[0].style.color="red"
}
}
</script>
```

[There is My code](http://jsfiddle.net/GFHVy/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers need to be functions. So you need something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].onmouseover = function() {
    // You don't want to use i in a function in a loop since i will
    // be different by the time the function gets called
    // this is document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i]
    this.childNodes[0].style.color="green"
}
```

You should probably also create the nodeList for the `<p>` tags outside of the loop so you're not traversing the DOM each time.

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(i=0;i<paras.length;i++){
    paras[i].onmouseover = function() { /* */ };
    paras[i].onmouseout = function() { /* */ };
}
```